# What is the simplest way to read an environment variables in R Shiny App on Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu, environment-variables, credentials

I want to remove credentials from a shiny app R script. The app is running on an internal instance of the shiny app open source server on a virtual machine running Ubuntu 20. The solution I am shooting for is:

1. Set environment variables in Ubuntu
2. Launch the R terminal and run Sys.getenv('myvariable'), and have the value returned

I have tried the following

**Add variables to ~/.profile**

After adding the variables at the bottom via

```
sudo nano ~/.profile
```

I saved ~/.profile, logged out, and logged back in (recommended from other post). On a new bash shell, I can enter

```
source ~/.profile
echo $myvariable
```

and the expected value is found.

However, when I open the R terminal, and enter

```
Sys.getenv('myvariable')
```

the returned value is blank

**Adding variable in R via Sys.setenv()**

The next option involves setting the variables in R. I would enter

```
Sys.setenv(myvariable='my value')
Sys.getenv('myvariable')
```

and the expected value is printed. However, if I quit the session the values are not maintained in a new session.

Additionally, I have tried save() and save.image() after setting the values with Sys.setenv(). When I load the .RData file, the variable is blank.

There is a solid chance this is something small, but I've not had luck with anything else I've found so far, so here we are.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how+to+make+environment+variables+persistent

Comment: What shell are you running? BASH or something else? What exactly did the contents of `.profile` look like? Did you relaunch R from the same terminal where you sourced the `.profile` file?

Comment: Try `~/.Renviron` (`ENV_VAR=VALUE` pairs) or `~/.Rprofile` (`Sys.setenv()` calls). See `?base::Startup` for official R doc, or a friendlier read https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/startup/vignettes/startup-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Jon Manese above answer was the best solution for me.

I visited `/etc/R/Renviron`, and added the variables I needed. Afterwards, I was able to reference the variables from the R terminal via `Sys.getenv()`

---

Also want to mention...before I edited the `Renviron` file, I tried adding the variables to the `~/.bashrc` file. After adding the variables there, I was able to reference those variables in bash terminal *without* having to use the `source` command. When variables were added to the `~/.profile` , I have to `source ~/.profile` to be able to reference in bash.

However, I was still not able to reference from the R terminal via `Sys.getenv()` until the `Renviron` file was edited.